# Trying to display all employees in a table that are over the age of 40 - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Not sure how to write a query to display all employees that are aged 40 or above

Not sure where to go from here

select First_Name, Last_Name, Birth_Date from Employees
where (sysdate - Birth_Date);

Answer (score 1):

Age is determined by when someone is born.  In Oracle the safest method is `add_months`, so:

```
where birth_date < add_months(sysdate, -12 * 40)
```

You can also specify this as:

```
where birthdate < sysdate - interval '40' year
```

This would generally work, but interval arithmetic can cause problems when leap years are involved.

Comment: thank you! Just started learning Oracle and enjoying it so far still learning the basics